# JSF SelectOneMenu onchange, onsubmit cancel reset value

Tags: ajax, jsf, onchange, selectonemenu, onsubmit

On a JSF SelectOneMenu, I have ajax event onchange, and with an onsubmit with a confirm question, when user abort the change, how could I reset the value on SelectOneMenu back to the original value?

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedFruit}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.fruits}"/>
  <a:support event="onchange" onsubmit="if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))return false;}" action="#{bean.loadFruitStats}" rerender="body"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

So on the above example, when user click 'No' on the confirm dialog, the action is not called, and rerender is not called, so the SelctOneMenu is on the updated "fruit" name, not the original one (so the fruit name and the fruit stats info doesnt match).  What can I do to synchronize them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h:selectOneMenu` can be reset back to the original value with a help of javascript.

1. First you will need to define an `id` to `h:selectOneMenu`. For example

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu id="selFruitId"...>
   ```
2. Add following (self-explanatory) java script to jsf page

   ```
   var currentValue;
   function saveCurrentValue(){
       //get html select element
       var element=document.getElementById("form:selFruitId");
       //saves currently selected value
       currentValue=element.value;
   }

   function areYouSure(){
       if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){
           //if canceled, restores previously saved value
           document.getElementById("form:selFruitId").value=currentValue;
           return false;
         }
    }
   ```
3. Then you need to intercept moment when user tries to **change** selected value using **mouse** (*onclick* event) or **keyboard** (*onkeypress* event, for example, left-right-up-down cursor keys or some other key) and **save** currently selected value for later.

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu id="selFruitId" 
                    onclick="saveCurrentValue()" onkeypress="saveCurrentValue()"...>
   ```
4. And, finally, before executing ajax, you need to call `function areYouSure()` which will, if canceled, restore saved (original) value back to `h:selectOneMenu`.

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedFruit}" id="selFruitId"
                    onclick="saveCurrentValue()" onkeypress="saveCurrentValue()">
       <f:selectItems value="#{bean.fruits}"/>
       <a:support event="onchange" onsubmit="areYouSure()" action="#{bean.loadFruitStats}" rerender="body"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   ```